# How to append Button inside a container that is being cloned

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a `<template>` tag and i have given it has a few children inside

I'm fetching a json file that has a few objects inside and running a forEach loop after i get the data in order to change the `<h1>` to be equal and display all the names that are inside the json file. Im also cloning the template and then appending the cloned template to a `main tag`.

The problem starts when i try to also create a button and append it inside the `<div class="content"> that is located inside the template.` I tried to get the `<div class="content">`   inside the loop and later create and append a button to the div i specified above (class = 'content') but whenever i try append it throws this error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null` this is the full code inside the loop.

if I try to change this line  `contentdiv.appendChild(btn);`  to this this `clone.appendChild(btn);`   then it works but the button is not inside the `<div class="content">` which i want it to be.

Anyone could help me understand what I am doing wrong here ?

```js
const data = [{
    fullname: "George Clooney"
}, {
    fullname: "Fred Astaire"
}]

data.forEach(actor => {
  //clone the template
  const clone = template.cloneNode(true);
  //get actor name and change the content to be = to the full name inside the json obj
  const actorName = clone.querySelector('.actor-name').textContent = actor.fullname;
  const contentdiv = document.querySelector('.content');
  //create button
  const btn = document.createElement('button');
  btn.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Read More'));
  btn.classList = 'btn'

  contentdiv.appendChild(btn);


  //apend the the clone to the main tag
  main.appendChild(clone);

});
```

```html
<template id='template'>
    <div class="content">
      <h1 class="actor-name">
      </h1>

    </div>
  </template>
```

Comment: I'm surprised you can do lookups off of things inside a template.  I thought the whole point of a template was that the inner contents were not parsed into the DOM except as text node(s).

Comment: You need `clone.querySelector('.content');`

Comment: I made you a snippet. Feel free to update to a [mcve]

Comment: the answer provided by @mplungjan worked as a charm, i was using template instead of clone I understood my mistake, Thanks a lot everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clone the content

```js
const data = [{
  fullname: "George Clooney"

}, {
  fullname: "Fred Astaire"

}]

const main = document.getElementById("main");

data.forEach(actor => {

  //clone the template
  const clone = document.getElementById("template").content.cloneNode(true);
  clone.querySelector('.actor-name').textContent = actor.fullname;
  const contentdiv = clone.querySelector('.content');
  const btn = document.createElement('button');
  btn.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Read More'));
  btn.classList = 'btn'
  contentdiv.appendChild(btn);
  main.appendChild(clone);
});
```

```html
<template id='template'>
    <div class="content">
      <h1 class="actor-name"></h1>
    </div>
  </template>
<div id="main"></div>
```